# selecting a node of treeview after postback - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am using a treeview control. I  am buliding the tree dynamically. sometimes the tree becomes larger and the down scroll bar is need to see the entire tree.
 user can select a node from the tree. if one node is selected ,i change the color of the node from server side.

my problem is that if a user selected a node which is bottom in the tree(means, the user used the down scrollbar to see that node), after postback it shows the top of the tree.to see the selected node the user need to use the down scroll bar.

I need to show the selected node after postback. How can I do this?

I am using c# and asp.net

Answer (score 1):

With help of jquery we can send the selected node id to the query string and on document.ready we can read back and highlight that node.
Have a look on the code:

Code behind onclick code:

```
public void TreeView1_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
        Page,
        Page.GetType(),
        "HighlightSelectedNode",
        "HighlightSelectedNode();",
        true
    );
}
```

and the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function HighlightSelectedNode() {
        var selectedNodeID = $('#<%= TreeView1.ClientID %>_SelectedNode').val();
        if (selectedNodeID != "") {
                document.location.href = "http://" + window.location.host
                    + window.location.pathname
                    + "?Node=" + selectedNodeID;
                return false;
        } else {
            // alert("Not found");
        }
    }

    // Highlight active node on pageload.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var querystring = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');
        var queryObj = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < querystring.length; i++) {
            var name = querystring[i].split('=')[0];
            var value = querystring[i].split('=')[1];
            queryObj[name] = value;
        }
        var nodeID = queryObj["Node"];
        $('#' + nodeID).css({ 'background-color': '#888'});              
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use update panel to work around this issue.